# Embedding YouTube video with Autoplay AND starting video at a particular time

Tags: youtube, embedding, autoplay

I was wondering if it is possible to autoplay an embedded YouTube video AND also have the video start at a certain point?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

You can just add the `&` to place another command in the embed script. The `?` starts the first command, the `&` adds another. The Start command is in seconds: 1min10sec=70secs. Then just top it off with an autoplay=1 to automatically start playing.

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/acktYyOGG6w?start=29&autoplay=1" width="1" height="1" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I ran into the same issue for deploying music for my church's website. The width and height were only to make it a pixel in size so the video won't show while it plays.

You see another example when you look at the playlist links.

```html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=of9C-8azVh8&index=4&list=PLBjhJqE72NDQPMNhB0peXyjDQNVxSext-
```